# Margin of Error: Why doesn't this form require p?

Tags: sampling, error

This page has a margin of error calculator:

https://www.surveymonkey.com/mp/margin-of-error-calculator/

Below, it gives a detailed example. The example conforms to my understanding of MOE. However, their calculator does not. Specifically, the calculator does not require p (the ratio of positive responses in the sample, 60% in the given example: "60% of respondents say they prefer Name A"). Instead, the calculator requires the population size, which is supposed to NOT affect MOE (except when the sample size is close to the population). So, what's going on? Where does the 60% get entered? If it doesn't get entered at all, how does the MOE calculator know what sigma is?

This is not an isolated example, here's another that has exactly the same mysterious property (that is, their calculator uses the population size, which is shouldn't, instead of p, which is should! It looks like they're assuming p=0.5):

https://www.qualtrics.com/experience-management/research/margin-of-error/

What are they doing? What am I mis-understanding?

Comment: The population size looks as if it is used solely for a "finite population correction" equivalent to your "except when the sample size is close to the population".  My guess is they take $p=\frac12$ to find a worst case for the binomial standard deviation, so end up with $\Phi^{-1}(1-\frac{\alpha}{2})\, \frac{\sqrt{\frac12(1-\frac12)}}{\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{\frac{N-n}{N-1}}$

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. I wish that they would explain what their calculator actually does instead of making it mysteriously do a different calculation than the one that is explained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Quick note: $p$ is properly the ratio of positive responses *in the population*. The ratio estimated from your *sample* is $\hat p$.)

Both calculators are probably assuming $p=0.5$. This gives a "safe" or "conservative" upper bound on the margin of error, because (to use the Qualtrics site's notation) the margin of error

$$MOE = Z^* \times \sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}$$

is maximized by $p=0.5$. Imagine plotting the parabola $p(1-p)$; it has a peak at $p=0.5$.

If you happen to be in a situation where you have good **prior** knowledge that $p$ is likely to be much closer to 0 or 1, you could plug that in instead of 0.5, and get a smaller MOE.

...but in practice, users who aren't statistically savvy might just plug in different guesses of $p$ until the calculator tells them they can get the MOE they want with just a tiny $n$, and **then** make up a story to justify why this $p$ is reasonable. I have to respect Qualtrics and SurveyMonkey for discouraging users from shooting themselves in the foot this way.

Comment: +1 The standard deviation given by the bound is also a very good approximation to the true standard deviation for population proportion between about 0.4 and 0.6 and still a fairly reasonable approximation out to near p=0.3 and p=0.7.  It's a perfectly reasonable, simple default for probabilities that aren't very small or large

Comment: Thank you. This is a simplified version of Henry's account. Respect, I suppose, but I would respect them even more if they did not confusingly explain one calculation while implementing a different one. (Esp. as they explicitly ask you to put the given numbers into the calculator, but you can't because there is no place to put p!)

Comment: @jackisquizzical Yes, Henry's right about the fpc -- sorry I missed that that was part of your question too. And I agree that the writeups around both calculators are misleading.